# Npm packages are not updated

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-update

Command: `npm outdated -g`

```
Package            Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint               6.8.0   6.8.0  7.17.0  vue-movies-app
eslint-plugin-vue    6.2.2   6.2.2   7.4.1  vue-movies-app
sass-loader          8.0.2   8.0.2  10.1.1  vue-movies-app
webpack             4.46.0  4.46.0  5.14.0  vue-movies-app
```

And i tried,  `sudo npm update -g` `npm update -g webpack@5.14.0`

But nothing changed? How is possible?

Comment: You could just update them in `package.json` delete `node_modules` and your `.lock` file and re-install.

Comment: I solved my self guys, I remove all packages and install latest version again. But now different problems also. I can not build my vue project. always getting error.. I hate webpack! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This has been [broken on and off for years](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11534#issuecomment-311148231), it's not just you. There's a [tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) to this, or you can do it with a little bit of scripting, for example `npm outdated -g | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed 1d | xargs npm i -g`